# Python unit-testing - How to patch an async call internal to the method I am testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Im using unittest.mock for building tests for my python code. I have a method that I am trying to test that contains a async call to another function. I want to patch that async call so that I can just have Mock return a testing value for the `asset id`, and not actually call the async method. I have tried many things I've found online, but none have worked thus far.

Simplified example below:

test.py

```
import pytest

from app.create.creations import generate_new_asset
from app.fakeapi.utils import create_asset

from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

@patch("app.fakeapi.utils.create_asset")
@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_generate_new_asset(mock_create):
    mock_create.return_value = 12345678

    await generate_new_asset()

    ...
```

creations.py

```
from app.fakeapi.utils import create_asset
...

async def generate_new_asset()
    ...
    # When I run tests this does not return the 12345678 value, but actually calls the `create_asset` method.
    return await create_asset(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing async code is bit tricky. If you are using python3.8 or higher `AsyncMock` is available.

Note: it will work only for `Python > 3.8`

I think in your case event loop is missing. Here is the code which should work, you may need to do few tweaks. You may also need to install `pytest-mock`. Having it as fixture will allow you to have mock different values for testing for different scenarios.

```
import asyncio
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock, Mock

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mock_create_asset(mocker):
   async_mock = AsyncMock()
   mocker.patch('app.fakeapi.utils.create_asset', side_effect=async_mock)
   return async_mock

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def event_loop():
    return asyncio.get_event_loop()

 @pytest.mark.asyncio
 async def test_generate_new_asset(mock_create_asset):
    mock_create_asset.return_value = 12345678
    await generate_new_asset()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I seem to still be having some issues. So I tried the above, and got to the point where I am getting an error about scope, "You tried to access the function scoped fixture mocker with a module scoped request object". So I tried to change the scoping to "function"/the default, but although the test now runs, I am still seeing the internal `create_asset` function being called instead of being mocked/patched.

Comment: you may need to mock where `create_asset` is called . did u try patching `import creations` `mocker.patch('creations.create_asset', side_effect=async_mock)`

Comment: Yeah I saw in your example the `.creations` was missing so in my code its `mocker.patch("app.fakeapi.utils.creations.create_asset', side_effect=async_mock")` if thats what you mean.

Comment: Yes, does that work for you ?

Comment: No, the `create_asset` method is still actually being called, its not being mocked for the test for some reason.

Comment: without seeing whole code , it is difficult to know where is it going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248706/discussion-between-macintosh-89-and-red).

Comment: In chat we found my issue, it was that I was patching where the method was being defined, not where it was being called

Comment: Look at the import that directly preceeds the call site: `from app.fakeapi.utils import create_asset`.  The import appears in `creations.py` so we mock `...creations.create_asset` and not `...utils.create_asset`.  Weird.